# Why doesn't this PL/SQL trigger show any result?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write a trigger that outputs the first name and last name of employees whose salary have been modified. This trigger will work when the old salary of the employee was less than 10,000 and with the modification, it's bigger than 10,000. This trigger has to be a row trigger

I have written this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER print_info
AFTER UPDATE OF salary ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE fname employees.first_name%type; lname employees.last_name%type;
BEGIN
IF(:OLD.salary < 10000 AND :NEW.salary > 10000) THEN
  dbms_output.put('fname, lname');
END IF;
END;
/
```

This code compiles and the trigger is created successfully, but when I update an employee's salary, within the trigger requirements, the trigger doesn't execute or doesn't show me anything.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A trigger cannot "show you anything". The trigger executes in the server, and the server has no way of displaying anything on anyone's screen. What it can do is write to a buffer (using DBMS_OUTPUT), then the client program can get and display the contents of the buffer. What is your client program? SQL*Plus?

Comment: Yes, I'm using sqlplus

Comment: Use `SET SERVEROUT ON` before updating an employee's salary

Comment: What is the purpose of displaying a static string?

Comment: In SQL\*Plus, type `show errors` immediately after running the block to see the compilation errors.

Comment: Thank you, using command ```SET SERVEROUT ON``` before updating salary worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `dbms_output.new_line;` after the `dbms_output.put` or use `dbms_output.put_line`

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER print_info
    AFTER UPDATE OF salary ON employees
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE fname employees.first_name%type; lname employees.last_name%type;
    BEGIN
    IF(:OLD.salary < 10000 AND :NEW.salary > 10000) THEN
      dbms_output.enable; 
      dbms_output.put('fname, lname '||:NEW.first_name||','||:NEW.last_name);
      dbms_output.new_line;
    END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help but this doesn't seem to work, I still get no result :(

Comment: hi i have enabled dbms_output ,try with the latest code

Comment: Hello, it doesn't seem to work. I have a rather odd issue, when I try to create the trigger via command line using sqlplus, it says trigger created with compilation errors, but  when i try to create the same trigger via the oracle sql developer app, it doesn't show me any error message. Other question, when i use sql developer to create the trigger, it shows me a window saying "enter binds", do i have to put something there? Maybe that's the issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: in sqlplus after running the code put 'show errors' and paste the output in your question

Comment: it doesn't let me put show errors.. after "END;" i have to put "/" to finish the script or it keeps adding new lines, if i do END; SHOW ERRORS /, it says compiled with errors but doesn't show any error message

Comment: use this select * from user_errors where lower(name)='print_info';

Comment: The backslash tells sqlplus to quit reading more lines and submit what it has. That's telling to to go ahead and execute the CREATE.  The SHOW ERRORS is a sqlplus command to be executed _after_ the CREATE has compiled and reported that it has errors. The SHOW SERRORS comes _after_ the backslash.  But this is still an astoundingly bad idea. You should not expect a trigger to 'show' anything.  And because of the way dbms_output works, it really shouln'd be used in production code as a means of communicating with the user.

Comment: I suggest you spend time familiarizing yourself with with some Oracle documentation. A couple starting points would [SQL*PLUS users guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/toc.htm)  and [2Day Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/toc.htm) Once you are comfortable with those take a look at Oracle [Database Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/toc.htm) .  Or the corresponding guides for your specific Oracle version (all currently supported versions have their own).

Comment: @EdStevens a [backslash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash) is "\". SQL\*Plus uses a [forward slash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)), also known as a slash.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Using ```SET SERVEROUT ON``` before updating the salary, I achieved what I wanted. I'm and CS student learning the basics, so I hope I didn't annoy you guys much. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - you are absolutely correct.  I must have had a brain-fart to have said it was a backslash.